# Map an array into array of objects with given object at the top of resulting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Suppose you have an array and an object that looks like this

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
const obj = {tree : -1, area: null}
```

How would you go about iterating over said array to return an array of objects like this, while having the initial value set to the object above.

Assume that `flatlist()` cant be used in this situation.

Desired output: `[{tree : -1, area: null}, {tree : 0, area: "a" },{tree : 1, area: "b" },{tree : 2, area: "c" } ]`

Comment: _Assume that `flatlist()` can't be used in this situation_ What is `flatlist()`?

Comment: ... and your try?

Comment: `[obj].concat(arr.map((area, tree) => ({tree, area})))` ? https://jsfiddle.net/5oepxuvg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"],
      obj = {tree : -1, area: null},
      
      result = [obj, ...arr.map((area,tree) => ({area,tree}))]
      
console.log(result)
```

On the other hand, you can make use of [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with your source object as initial resulting array value:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"],
      obj = {tree : -1, area: null},
      
      result = arr.reduce((r,area,tree) => (r.push({area,tree}),r), [obj])
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: The exact thing i was looking for was, but you put me in the right direction, Thanks!    
```result = [obj, ...arr.map((area, tree ) => ({ tree , area}))]```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one element at beginning and use map

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];

const results = [null, ...arr].map((area, i) => ({ tree: i - 1, area }));

console.log(results);
```